# Из ereg в preg_math

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Подскажите, как из `ereg` переделать в `preg_match`.

```
if( (! ereg( '^[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+' . '@' . '[-!#$%&\'*+\\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\.' . '[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+$', $email )) or (empty( $email )) ) $stop .= $lang['reg_err_6'];
```

По сути `ereg('aaa') = preg_match('/aaa/')`, но выражение

```
if( (! preg_match( '/^[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+' . '@' . '[-!#$%&\'*+\\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\.' . '[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+$/', $email )) or (empty( $email )) ) $stop .= $lang['reg_err_6'];
```

не работает.

Comment: Погодите, вы допускаете e-mail `!{{{#@#{{{#.{#*{` ?) 

Кстати, во избежание ворнингов рекомендую условия поменять местами (`empty($email) or preg_match(...)`), тогда если мыло пустое, проверка проводиться не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> По сути ereg('aaa') = preg_match('/aaa/'), но выражение

Именно так, а у вас получается `'/aа/aa/'` Нужно экранировать ограничители внутри выражения: `'/aа\/aa/'` Или использовать в качестве ограничителей символы, которые не встречаются в выражении (хотя в вашей регулярке, по моему, таких символов нет): `'~aа/aa~';`

Comment: экранировал все / 

    if( (! preg_match( '/^[-!#$%&\'*+\\.\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+' . '@' . '[-!#$%&\'*+\\\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\.' . '[-!#$%&\'*+\\.\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+$/', $email )) or (empty( $email )) ) $stop .= $lang['reg_err_6'];

но все равно не работает, пишет ошибку Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '0'

Comment: У вас путаница со слешами. `*+\\\/0-9` - тут 3 слеша воспринимаются как один. Разбейте их как-либо.

Comment: Либо так:

    preg_match( '@^[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+' . '\@' . '[-!#$%&\'*+\\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\.' . '[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+$@', $email );

Comment: по моему \\\\\\/ не воспринимаются как один а экранируется сам слеш \\ и экранируется слеш /, разве нет?
А пример с @ помог, спасибо

Comment: Раз у вас выводится ошибка `Unknown modifier '0'`, значит нет.

Дело в том, что в данном случае обратный слеш экранируется два раза. Первый раз при обработки [single quoted](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.syntax.single) строки и второй раз уже [в регулярном выражении](http://php.net/regexp.reference.escape)

Т.н. если выполнить `echo '*+\\\/0-9';`, то будет выведено `*+\\/0-9`, что в регулярном выражении будет интерпретировавший, как один экранированный обратный слеш.

Comment: точно же, экранирование два раза тут ) огромное спасибо :)

Answer (score -1):

Советую сначала почитать как пользоваться данной командой [preg_match](http://www.php.su/functions/?preg-match). Там не две переменные а три: маска, по которой сравнивать, что сравнивать, куда класть совпадение.

Comment: Советую, прежде чем написать, ознакомиться с примерами (которые специально предеведны ниже) по вашей же ссылке http://www.php.su/functions/?preg-match, и учесть что третий параметр не обязателен.

Comment: если ему нужна только проверка без дальнейшей работы с емайлами которые внутри найдутся то не вижу смысла в том чтобы заменять eregi. потому и ответил что ему нужен еще один параметр и потом проверять просто count если 0 то никакого мыла нет внутри.

Comment: Она возвращает кол-во совпадений, не надо никакой count по условию вопроса проверять.

Comment: вопрос. что вам даст количество если дальше опять ему придется их выбирать оттуда снова повторяя эту же выборку?

Comment: Зачем ее повторять, если надо тупо проверить мыло на валидность? Если 0( = false) - не валидно, если больше( = true) - валидно.

> Функция preg_match() возвращает количество найденных соответствий. Это может быть 0 (совпадения не найдены) и 1, поскольку preg_match() прекращает свою работу после первого найденного совпадения.

Comment: тогда зачем eregi убирать если она это спокойно делает. preg-match ставят когда надо дальше работать с тем что найдется в соответствии. иначе не вижу смысла его юзать

Comment: Например, <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php">потому что</a> 

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: [eregi](http://php.net/eregi) - deprecated и будет удалена в будущих версиях PHP. Кроме того, ereg* - *значительно* медленней preg_*.

Comment: Sh4dow, именно. меняем устаревшие функции на новые. в этом и суть.